# Panels + Recaptcha : how to add a (re)Captcha in my panels view?

Tags: 7, panels, captcha

I've just installed Panels 3.1 on my D7 website.

There is no options to add a Recaptcha form on my Panels view.

Where should I find that ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You don't usually add a recaptcha directly to Panels; you'll want to add it to the appropriate form(s) (comment, registration, etc.)  When you do so, adding the appropriate form in Panels should automatically pull in the recaptcha as well.

Comment: I've add (re)captcha to comment and registration form. But I didn't see where I can add a recaptcha when I submit a node (anonymous users can submit node : I need recaptcha on this specific node).
I'm a little lost ... :)

Comment: When **general form** is added to **panels** : I have everything.  But I just want to display 4 of 6 elements of my node/add form : (submit, captcha, title, body, not field 1 and field 2). I find a way to add submit button, title and body. But nothing for Captcha. What should I do ?

Comment: If you want to hide fields from users, you have a couple options.  You could use the Field permissions module to remove the permissions from authenticated users, or you could use a custom module and `hook_form_alter()` to remove the fields.

Comment: "Field permissions module to remove the permissions from authenticated users" <<<<
Need to find some screenshoot with that, anyway thank you for the tips

Comment: Do __not__ use Panels to only display parts of a Form API-form. It will (most likely) __not work__ as you expect. (I wish we'd just block the ability all together, but that's a different story). There's an issue in the queue about if it you want the details. You should do what @PatrickKenny said instead.